# Problem of loading TableView in uiviewcontroller in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController and also i have UITableViewController ( this is for making table view). I am calling UITableViewController from UIViewController in self window. This is calling well and I am also getting output. But I want to show only 3 Rows and I am seeing 3 Rows with title are showing and also extra raw with blank title are showing on Simulator. It means it is covering whole windows. How will i fix for 3 Rows displaying ?

thanks in advance.

I am loading by this function code..

```
 MyViewController *History_Back = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[window addSubview:History_Back.view];  


[self.view addSubview:History_Back.view];
```

........

This is calling for Tableview but want to open in same windows. I am new in iPhone so it may i am right.

Answer (score 0):

Quick alternative would be to use 3 UITableViewCell instead of a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Push History_Back on self.navigationController